# Fetch success method not triggering, only showing 'parsererror', but browser receives data

Tags: json, backbone.js, fetch

I have two collections, my BlueCollection works fine loading data from an array stored in a variable, but my RedCollection has some problems fetching data from a different array which doesn't use a variable. Am I missing something?

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pg123851/4/)

```
BlueCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: BlueModel,
});

RedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: RedModel,
  url: 'data/data.json' // It is from http://www.localhost:3000/data/data.json
});
```

BlueCollection has no problems loading this data.

```
var blue = [
  {id: 1, title: 'blue 1 - '},
  {id: 2, title: 'blue 2 - '},
  {id: 3, title: 'blue 3'}
];
```

But RedCollection has problems fetching this data

```
// http://www.localhost:3000/data/data.json
[
  {id: 1, title: 'red 1 - '},
  {id: 2, title: 'red 2 - '},
  {id: 3, title: 'red 3'}
]
```

However, when I check firebug, I see that the browser receives the data, but fetch `success` method never triggers, only `complete` method triggers with the message `parsererror` 
[image: Backbone fetch response]

The full code is this:

```
var blue = [
    {id: 1, title: 'blue 1 - '},
  {id: 2, title: 'blue 2 - '},
  {id: 3, title: 'blue 3'}
];

// http://www.localhost:3000/data/data.json
/* No variable, this json should be fetched from RedCollection
[
    {id: 1, title: 'red 1 - '},
  {id: 2, title: 'red 2 - '},
  {id: 3, title: 'red 3'}
]
*/

BlueModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
RedModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

BlueCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: BlueModel,
});

RedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: RedModel,
  url: 'http://www.localhost:3000/data/data.json'
  /* 
        [
            {id: 1, title: 'red 1'},
        {id: 2, title: 'red 2'},
        {id: 3, title: 'red 3'}
        ]
    */
});

BlueView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new BlueCollection(blue);
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(item) {
        self.addAll(item);
    }, this);
  },

  addAll: function(item) {
    $('#blue').append(item.get('title'));
  }
});

RedView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new RedCollection; 

    this.collection.fetch({ 
            success: function () {
            console.log('Success'); // Never shows, but console shows content loaded
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                console.log(xhr);
            },  
          complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                console.log(textStatus); // Only this log shows with: parsererror
            }
        });
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    var self = this;

    _.each(this.collection.models, function(item) {
        self.addAll(item);
    }, this);
  },

  addAll: function(item) {
    $('#red').append(item.get('title'));
  }
});

blueview = new BlueView;
redview = new RedView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember a json property has to be inside [""](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp). Modify the json like this:

```
[
  {"id": 1, "title": "red 1 - "},
  {"id": 2, "title": "red 2 - "},
  {"id": 3, "title": "red 3"}
]
```